# How to parse slice of structs in Go Gin multipart request

Tags: go, slice, multipart, go-gin

This is my application:

```golang
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("user", func(c *gin.Context) {
        type address struct {
            City    string `form:"city"`
            Country string `form:"country"`
        }
        type user struct {
            Name      string    `form:"name"`
            Addresses []address `form:"addresses"`
        }

        var payload user
        err := c.Bind(&payload)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{})
            return
        }

        file, err := c.FormFile("image")
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{})
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("TODO: save user image %s\n", file.Filename)
        fmt.Printf("TODO: save user %s with addresses %d\n", payload.Name, len(payload.Addresses))
    })
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

This is my request:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/user' \
--form 'name="John Smith"' \
--form 'addresses[0][city]="London"' \
--form 'addresses[0][country]="United Kingdom"' \
--form 'image=@"/Users/me/Documents/app/fixtures/user.jpeg"'
```

The problem is that addresses are nil. I'm not able to find example of how to correctly deserialize multipart request with embedded slice data. what am I doing wrong?

---

update:

I exported the curl command from Postman. apparently, the POST method is implicit if you have "--form" parameter. here are logs from my app:

```
TODO: save user image user.jpeg
TODO: save user John Smith with addresses 0
```

---

update 2:

Turns out that sending array like this is wrong:

> --form 'addresses[0][city]="London"'

What gin supports by default is sending multiple fields with the same name, which then will be turned into an array:

> --form 'addresses=...
> --form 'addresses=...

so that led me to a somewhat hacky solution of passing each address as query parameters and then parsing them individually:

request:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/user' \
--form 'name="John Smith"' \
--form 'addresses="?city=London&country=UK"' \
--form 'addresses="?city=Berlin&country=Germany"'
--form 'image=@"/Users/foo/bar/baz/user.jpeg"' \
```

the app:

```golang
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("user", func(c *gin.Context) {
        type address struct {
            City    string `form:"city"`
            Country string `form:"country"`
        }
        type user struct {
            Name      string   `form:"name"`
            Addresses []string `form:"addresses"` // collection_format:"multi"
        }

        var payload user
        err := c.Bind(&payload)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{})
            return
        }

        var addresses []address
        for _, path := range payload.Addresses {
            parsed, err := url.Parse(path)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }
            query := parsed.Query()
            addresses = append(addresses, address{
                City:    query.Get("city"),
                Country: query.Get("country"),
            })
        }

        file, err := c.FormFile("image")
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{})
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("TODO: save user image %s\n", file.Filename)
        fmt.Printf("TODO: save user %s with addresses %d\n", payload.Name, len(addresses))

    })
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

So please, if someone have a better solution please let me know.

Comment: My suggestion is to check on the server side if the request body is in the expected format. Try to read the value directly from the form to confirm that the problem is the parser. From the code snipped I see no problem so far. Also, the request that you point to is GET. Your endpoint is suppose to be POST.

Comment: @VictorVieira I updated my question, I am catching requests with a debugger. Name and image file are passed just fine, but the array is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Solution is instead of defining addresses as slice of string define it as slice of address and pass each address as json instead of query params.

request -

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/getForm' \
--form 'name ="Zargam"' \
--form 'addresses="{\"city\":\"Delhi\",\"country\":\"India\"}"' \
--form 'addresses="{\"city\":\"Shanghai\",\"country\":\"China\"}"'
```

Code-

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type address struct {
    City    string `form:"city"`
    Country string `form:"country"`
}
type user struct {
    Name      string    `form:"name"`
    Addresses []address `form:"addresses"` // collection_format:"multi"
}

func processForm(c *gin.Context) {
    var payload user
    err := c.Bind(&payload)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{})
        return
    }
    payloadByte, _ := json.Marshal(payload)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "success", "data": string(payloadByte)})
    return
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/getForm", processForm)
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080 (for windows "localhost:8080")
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly